# Plot hollow circles in plt.scatter

Tags: matplotlib, scatter

I would like to plot a scatter plot by using 2 indexes [ChildrenHeight, ParentHeight] for a categorical variable: [gender]. However, I have tired many approaches to draw a empty circle with distinct edgecolors.

I have tried:

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, marker = 'o',facecolors='none', cmap=plt.cm.Set1)
```

but it just gave me full circles:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `cmap` in that way, try `fillstyle = 'none'` command : https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html

For example,

```
x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)
y = np.random.randint(100, size=100)

plt.plot(x,y,lw=0, marker='o', fillstyle='none')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, if you want tu use `plt.scatter`:

```
plt.scatter(x,y,marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But when I tried:  `plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y,marker='o', facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')` It seems that facecolors doesn't work. The color inside the circle still appears

Comment: Because the y variable is a categorical value with 0 and 1 and I have to plot these two with different colors

Comment: Try to cancel `c=y` and try to use `edgecolors=y`, where `y` are different colors.
You can store them in an array under a `if` condition, something like `if y=1 -> color = red; else -> color=gray`.